# NullPointerException when passing JPanel to CardLayout

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception, cardlayout

I asked a similar question not too long ago about using multiple classes for JPanels within a JFrame, after much improving my code I've now come across an obstacle with CardLayout.

I get a NullPointerException when tring to show my "2" screen which is just a BaseScreen that I will later use other classes to inherit its properties. After changing this code,

```
final CardLayout cardL = new CardLayout();
```

from

```
CardLayout cardL;
```

outside of my contructor I now get no JPanels appearing!

Here's my code:

**Login Class:**

```
/*Login Screen class for allowing
multiple levels of access and security*/

//Imports library files
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

//Creates a LoginScreen class that extends the JFrame library class
class LoginScreen extends JFrame {

    //Creates a swing components and CardLayout for organising JPanels
JFrame container = this;
JPanel cardScreen;
JPanel screen = new JPanel();
Image ProgramIcon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("imageIco.png");
ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon ("Logo.png");
JLabel icon = new JLabel(logo);
JLabel username = new JLabel("Username");
JLabel password = new JLabel("Password");
JTextField user = new JTextField(18);
JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(18);
JButton login = new JButton("Login");
JLabel errorInfo = new JLabel("");
int WIDTH = 800;
int HEIGHT = 500;
int currentPanel = 1;

public static void main(String[] args){
//Sets the GUI (Look and Feel) to the NimROD theme
    try {UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.nilo.plaf.nimrod.NimRODLookAndFeel");}
    catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e){ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GUI Load Error: Unsupported");}
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GUI Load Error: NimROD Missing");} 
    catch (InstantiationException e) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GUI Load Error: Instantiation Missing");} 
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GUI Load Error: Illegal Access"); } 

//Creates a new LoginScreen via the LoginScreen method
    LoginScreen LS = new LoginScreen();
}

public LoginScreen(){
//Adds the JPanel to the JFrame and set the JFrame's properties
//Sets the main JPanel to CardLayout platform and adds other JPanels it
    final CardLayout cardL = new CardLayout();
    cardScreen = new JPanel();
    cardScreen.setLayout(cardL);
    cardScreen.add(screen, "1");;
    BaseScreen base = new BaseScreen();
    cardScreen.add(base, "2");
    container.setIconImage(ProgramIcon);
    container.setTitle("Login");
    container.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    container.setResizable(false);
    container.setVisible(true);
    container.add(screen);
    container.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//Place the components on the JPanel and set there absolute posistions
    screen.setLayout(null);
    screen.add(username);
    screen.add(password);
    screen.add(user);
    screen.add(pass);
    screen.add(login);
    screen.add(icon);
    Dimension iconSize = icon.getPreferredSize();
    Dimension usernameSize = username.getPreferredSize();
    Dimension passwordSize = password.getPreferredSize();
    Dimension loginSize = login.getPreferredSize();
    Dimension userSize = user.getPreferredSize();
    Dimension passSize = pass.getPreferredSize();
    username.setBounds(252,170,usernameSize.width,usernameSize.height);
    password.setBounds(495,170,passwordSize.width,passwordSize.height);
    user.setBounds(180,200,userSize.width,userSize.height);
    pass.setBounds(420,200,passSize.width,passSize.height);
    login.setBounds(375,250,loginSize.width,loginSize.height);
    icon.setBounds(250,50,iconSize.width,iconSize.height);

    login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { 
            cardL.show(cardScreen,"2");
            }
        }); 
}
```

**BaseScreen Class:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;


class BaseScreen extends JPanel{

JPanel screen = this;
JButton logout = new JButton("Logout");
ImageIcon title = new ImageIcon("title.png");
JLabel header = new JLabel(title);

public BaseScreen(){

    screen.setVisible(true);
    screen.setLayout(null);
    screen.add(logout);
    screen.add(header);
    Dimension headerSize = header.getPreferredSize();
    Dimension logoutSize = logout.getPreferredSize();
    logout.setBounds(720,440,logoutSize.width,logoutSize.height);
    header.setBounds(0,0,headerSize.width,headerSize.height);

    ButtonHandler handle = new ButtonHandler();
    logout.addActionListener(handle);
}

    public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        if (event.getSource() == logout){

        }
    }
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help/tips.

Here's the old thread: [Using multiple classes with the same JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827202/using-multiple-classes-with-the-same-jframe)

EDIT:

Here's the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at LoginScreen$1.actionPerformed(LoginScreen.java:84)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6288)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6053)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4651)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:616)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:614)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:613)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: Please show your exception stack trace. Ideally, reduce your sample code to a short but complete example demonstrating the problem, too.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have too much time right now but I'll cut down the code ASAP. Just learning the ropes of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about your `NullPointerException`, but your example doesn't work.

```
class LoginScreen extends JFrame
```

It's very rare to need to ever extend from a top level container, like `JFrame`, it's unnecessary and just complicates matters, use something like `JPanel` instead and add it to a frame you created...

```
JFrame container = this;
```

IMHO, this is a bad idea.  It just confuses the issue.  If you really need some way to reference the parent object, use `this` directly...

You call `container.setVisible(true)` before you've finished adding components to the frame, this is never a good idea.  In fact, when I loaded your program correctly (starting from within the EDT), nothing appeared on the frame - but that was probably due to the next problem...

You create `cardScreen`, you create `screen`, you add `screen` to `cardScreen` then you add `screen` directly to the frame...This has effectivly removed `screen` from the `cardScreen` container...this might explain you `NPE`.

`screen.setLayout(null)` this is NEVER a good idea.  Personally, I can't stand non-resizable frames, I know there are times to use them, but that doesn't mean I need to like them.  I think I might stop answering questions that use null layouts without good reason :P

Take the time to learn and understand layout managers, they are one of the most powerful features of Swing

- [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
- [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it's all working now and I've taken your other comments into account and appended my code. Learning more every day!